# Ubuntu 14.04 Sound through Headphones but not through Speaker

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I am running dual boot on lenovo yoga 2 pro. I set my default sound card to be the pc-speakers since alsamixer kept randomly changing it to the hdmi after every reboot. There is no sound through the pc-speaker but when I insert a headphone in, there is sound for the headphone.

The output devices also only now show headphones. When i unplug, it goes back to speaker but no sound.